# Openpyxl : the load_workbook function was automatically called when the open function run

Tags: python, openpyxl

the code as below

```
from openpyxl import *
wb = load_workbook(r'./test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
ws1 = wb.create_sheet("Mysheet")
ws.delete_cols(2)
wb.save('./test.xlsx')
tagui_output = open('C:/Downloads/TagUI_Windows/tagui/src/tagui_py/tagui_py.txt','w')
tagui_output.write(temp_result)
tagui_output.close()
```

the output of code as below

```
C:\Downloads\TagUI_Windows\tagui\flows\samples> python .\excel2.py
fn of load_workbook = ./test.xlsx
fn of load_workbook = C:/Downloads/TagUI_Windows/tagui/src/tagui_py/tagui_py.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Downloads\TagUI_Windows\tagui\flows\samples\excel2.py", line 7, in <module>
    tagui_output = open('C:/Downloads/TagUI_Windows/tagui/src/tagui_py/tagui_py.txt','w')
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 316, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 94, in _validate_archive
    raise InvalidFileException(msg)
openpyxl.utils.exceptions.InvalidFileException: filename=C:/Downloads/TagUI_Windows/tagui/src/tagui_py/tagui_py.txt openpyxl does not support .txt file format, please check you can open it with Excel first. Supported formats are: .xlsx,.xlsm,.xltx,.xltm
```

It seems the load_workbook function was automatically called when the open('C:/Downloads/TagUI_Windows/tagui/src/tagui_py/tagui_py.txt','w') function run,why this  happened ?

Comment: This is why you shouldn't use `import *` unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've conflict for python io function `open()` with `openpyxl.open`.

`from openpyxl import *` is importing all functions which shadows built-in `open()`. Restrict `from openpyxl import`s to limited function calls which you use.

Also, use `with open("path/tagui_py.txt", "w") as tagui_output:` for better file-handling.